# Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist Exception Value: Cart has no owner. Django-eCommerce

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a webshop on Django, and I'm facing one problem. Everything works perfectly if I'm running this code on my PC like `python manage.py runserver`. But when I'm trying to run it in my local network like `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, then I have this error:

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /add-to-cart/vw_golf/bags/
Cart has no owner.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.1.165:8000/add-to-cart/vw_golf/bags/
Django Version: 3.2.4
Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Cart has no owner.
Exception Location: C:\Users\dinar\PycharmProjects\shop_scnd_copy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py, line 197, in __get__
Python Executable:  C:\Users\dinar\PycharmProjects\shop_scnd_copy\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\dinar\\PycharmProjects\\shop_scnd_copy\\venv\\django3-ecommerce',
 'C:\\Users\\dinar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\dinar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\dinar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\dinar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\dinar\\PycharmProjects\\shop_scnd_copy\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\dinar\\PycharmProjects\\shop_scnd_copy\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

These are my classes `Cart` and `Customer`:

```py
class Cart(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey('Customer', verbose_name='Kunde', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(CartProduct, blank=True, related_name='related_cart')
    total_products = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    final_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, default=0, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Gesamtpreis')
    in_order = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    for_anonymous_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class Customer(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Kunde', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Handynummer', null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Email', default='')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Adresse', null=True, blank=True)
    orders = models.ManyToManyField('Order', verbose_name='Bestellungen', related_name='related_order')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Kunde: {} {}".format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
```

This is my view:

```
class AddToCartView(CartMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ct_model, product_slug = kwargs.get('ct_model'), kwargs.get('slug')
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=ct_model)
        product = content_type.model_class().objects.get(slug=product_slug)
        cart_product, created = CartProduct.objects.get_or_create(
            user=self.cart.owner, cart=self.cart, content_type=content_type, object_id=product.id
        )
        if created:
            self.cart.products.add(cart_product)
        recalc_cart(self.cart)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/cart/')
```

And this is my `CartMixin`:

```py
class CartMixin(View):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            customer = Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
            if not customer:
                customer = Customer.objects.create(
                    user=request.user
                )
            cart = Cart.objects.filter(owner=customer, in_order=False).first()
            if not cart:
                cart = Cart.objects.create(owner=customer)
        else:
            cart = Cart.objects.filter(for_anonymous_user=True).first()
            if not cart:
                cart = Cart.objects.create(for_anonymous_user=True)
        self.cart = cart
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Are you logged in when using `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: try to change  if not cart: to if not cart.exists(): in CartMixin when you not logged

Comment: When I logged in as admin, then it works. But when not, then there is error

Comment: I fixed the problem. I added a SESSION ID and it works